# Can I prevent/avoid the alert when reloading a form in my page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple form in my page as shown in the pic.

Is there a way to avoid the alert??. I find it annoying and in my case I don't lose any important info if I reload the form.

[image: Are you sure you want to reload the page]

```
<form name="theForm" method="get"> <!-- Changed from "post" to "get" but alert keeps showing -->
Start Point     ( 
<input type="text" name="pt0x" size="4" onkeydown="keyDownPt(event, document.theForm.pt0x.value, 0, 'x')"/>,
<input type="text" name="pt0y" size="4" onkeydown="keyDownPt(event, document.theForm.pt0y.value, 0, 'y')"/> ); </br>
...
</form>
```

I don't have a "send" button because I update my thing onkeydown event. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Hey! Good question, mind posting some code, especially the <form> part, if possible? Is it a refresh (in the code, via js or html) that causes this pop-up?

Comment: The alert is shown when I reload the page in the browser (ex. Cmd+r). I don't reload the form programmatically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not actually doing anything with it, you could get rid of the form entirely.

EDIT for completeness:Not using a form tag is perfectly valid HTML and validates as HTML4 strict, HTML5 and XHTML transitional. The W3C validator is [here](http://validator.w3.org/check).

Comment: I think getting rid of the form is not the best solution but In this specific case when I never send the values to the server (just update other elements using js) It worked. Thanks

Comment: @nacho4d: Thanks for the tick, but I do not understand why getting rid of the form can be anything other than a good thing, especially as it is not adding anything, apart from your page reload problem, to the page.

Comment: It seemed to me that having text fields not in a form was some kind incorrect/incomplete. I don't usually program in html/js so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use GET as method on the form tag instead of POST.

Since POST is meant for "uploading" data to the server, the browser will rightfully warn the user about reposting the the form, but if you simply GET the data the browser assumes it's a safe action to repeat.

**EDIT**: I misread the dialog in the question. It's not about reposting, but about discarding form data... Try using GET instead of POST anyway (if you're not already doing it), see if it has any effect.

**EDIT2**: I would be surprised if it's any simple way of disabling it using javascript (the user could probably disabled in the browser, though), since it's a reminder that you're about to discard data. If the user wants to reload the page, the browser warns that the form will be discarded but the user can dismiss it.

This should not be an issue anyway. If you need to reload the application for actual production use for some reason, try to rewrite the program to work without reloading (as this may cause the browser to re-download the code). E.g. if you want to reload just to reset the form, just add a reset button.

Comment: `<form method="get" ... >`  If the form's data is under a Kilobyte you should be fine in all modern browsers.

Comment: Changed to get but it didn't work for me. Just to make sure I am not passing more than 1Kb, How can I measure the data size?

Comment: Post to a script that outputs the filesize() of $_POST and it should tell you. However, it's probably not worth the trouble. That form should be waayyy under 1kb.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try disabling the submit button, since you don't intend to post the data in the first place.

The easy (and ugly) way to do this is by adding  a false return statemen on your form's `onsubmit` handler, like so:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Good-luck!

Comment: Didn't work either :( . Just one question : Why this would be an ugly solution?